# How can I sort the data in a table over four columns?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table in db2 that I want to sort. The table has four columns.
The data looks like:

```
KEY Type    GROUP_ID    SpecialType
2   T02     700         S
2   T01     500         R
1   T02     300         B
2   T02     600         S
1   T02     400         S
2   T02     700         B
1   T01     400         R
1   T02     300         S
2   T02     600         B
```

The sort order has the following rules:

- First sort key is `KEY`
- Special Type R should be always come first in each Key group.
- S may come after R and B element, but it should have the same group_id
- If S has the same group_id with the R specialtype, it should come after this R Specialtype

The result should look like in this form

```
KEY Type    GROUP_ID    SpecialType
1   T01     400         R
1   T02     400         S
1   T02     300         B
1   T02     300         S
2   T01     500         R
2   T02     600         B
2   T02     600         S
2   T02     700         B
2   T02     700         S
```

I tried this `ORDER BY`, but it doesn't work:

```
select * from myTable
ORDER BY KEY, GROUP_ID, CASE WHEN SPECIALTYPE = 'R' THEN 1
                             WHEN SPECIALTYPE='B' THEN 2
                             ELSE 3 END
```

Any Idea??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should return the list in the order you provided. It includes an analytic function in the sort which counts the number of times 'R' is included in each GroupId in order to have those groupIds listed first.

```
SELECT
    t.KeyId,
    t.TypeName,
    t.GroupId,
    t.SpecialType
FROM @Table t
ORDER BY 
    KeyId,
    CASE WHEN SpecialType = 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t.SpecialType = 'R' THEN SpecialType END) OVER (PARTITION BY t.GroupId) DESC,
    GroupId,
    SpecialType
```

Comment: Honestly, I did not understand how your order statement works but the result seems to be correct. I will check in more rows to ensure

Comment: The COUNT(CASE WHEN) portion tries to enforce the "If S has the same group_id with the R specialtype, it should come after this R Specialtype". Right now it sorts any SpecialType which shares the same GroupId immediately after the R. These order by may not work with a larger dataset depending on additional requirements if there are more than 1 R for a Key or if another letter besides S that shares the same GroupId with R.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.

Try `select * from myTable ORDER BY KEY, CASE WHEN SPECIALTYPE = 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, GROUP_ID`

Comment: It does not cover the first sort. `
1   T01     400         R
1   T02     400         S`

Comment: Is it type should be the second key on the orderby ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create table to define the sort preference like this

```
Preferance
---------------------------------------------
SpecialType         OrderNo
---------------------------------------------
R                  1
B                  2
S                  3
```

Now join this table with your main table and select order column from this table and use orderNo column to sort your record something like this

```
select T.*, P.orderNo  
from myTable  T
  INNER JOIN Preferance P ON T.Preferance = P.Preferance
ORDER BY T.KEY, T.GROUP_ID, P.orderNo
```

Comment: group_id is also important

Comment: You can add the group id before p.OrderNo, or according to your condition, let me update that, What I try to explain you is that, create a separate table which can help you to define the order whatever you want, not only for those 3 value but any number of values